# VBA How do I adjust my code to speed up the loop process?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a worksheet change event that, when 3 adjacent cells are filled in columns C,D and E it is documented in a different sheet with the date as well as the sheet that where the cells have been filled in.

Then every occurrence of date data is summed up and plotted on a calendar essentially showing how many entries have occurred for everyday of the year.

The issue is, is that the code loops through all days of the year which makes it incredibly slow, is there any way to make adjustments so it doesn't loop through everything or at least to speed up the process?

This is the code for the loops in question:

```
With Sheets("Log")
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dCol) _
                    .End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    dfCell.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dfCell.Offset(, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
    dfCell.Offset(, 2).Value = srAddress

    Dim arrDates As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim DateRange As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ClmnAmnt As Long
    Dim ClmnDate() As Variant
    Dim AddrArr() As Variant
    Dim ClmnNmbr As Long
    Dim shtNames As Range
    Dim TypCount As Long
    Dim FrstLetter() As Variant
    Dim SheetIdent As String
    Dim lastAddrs As String

    For RowCount = 1 To 60
        Select Case RowCount
            Case 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            DateRange = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F" & RowCount & ":AJ" & RowCount))
                For TypCount = 1 To 3
                    SheetIdent = .Cells(RowCount + TypCount, 5).Value
                        For ClmnNmbr = 1 To DateRange
                        
                            ReDim AddrArr(DateRange)
                            AddrArr(ClmnNmbr) = .Cells(RowCount, ClmnNmbr + 5).Value
                            
                            Set arrDates = .Range("A60:A" & LastRow)
                            Set shtNames = .Range("B60:B" & LastRow)
                            
                            
                            ReDim FrstLetter(DateRange)
                            FrstLetter(ClmnNmbr) = Application.CountIfs(arrDates, AddrArr(ClmnNmbr), shtNames, SheetIdent)
                            
                            Worksheets("Log").Cells(TypCount + RowCount, ClmnNmbr + 5).Value = Application.Transpose(FrstLetter(ClmnNmbr))
                            
                            
                        Next ClmnNmbr
                    Next TypCount
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next RowCount

End With
```

Comment: `For RowCount = 2 To 57 Step 5`, set `LastRow ` outside your loop

Comment: For speed, you can turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` while the macro is running, set to `False` at the start of the loop and `True` at the end. Also, since you're making changes to the sheet, you can temporarily disable sheet recalculations as well with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. Don't forget to set it back to auto (`xlCalculationAutomatic`). These two things should improve the execution speed by a large amount.

Comment: 1) there seems to be a lot of code inside the loops that aren't affected by the loops.   Move all that outside the loops. 2) use the Variant Array technique: copy the data to an array at the start, loop over the array modifying it as you go.  Copy the array back to the range at the end 3) be careful to avoid an event cascade 4) are you sure you need to run all this code for every change? Maybe you could reduce what runs based on what cell(s) or values changed

Comment: Doing all of @Toddleson 's suggestions helped tremendously. The loop right now loops through multiple rows going down the sheet with multiple ranges which is captured in the array ```FrstLetter``` but even though I see how it would tremendously speed up the process as @chris neilsen said, I wouldn't begin to know how to express that back out all in one go to multiple areas.

Answer (score 0):

Treat each month as a separate array of 3 rows by 28/29/30/31 columns then you can read, update counts and write back.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateCounts()
    
    Const COL_LETTER = "E"
    
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, counts, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, dates, letters
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, d As Long, m As Long, r As Long
    
    With Sheets("Log")
    
        ' fill data
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngA = .Range("A60:A" & LastRow)
        Set rngB = .Range("B60:B" & LastRow)
       
        ' scan down sheet rows 2 to 57
        For m = 1 To 12 ' jan to dec
            r = 2 + (m - 1) * 5
            LastCol = .Cells(r, "AK").End(xlToLeft).Column
            d = LastCol - 5 ' no of days
            
            If d >= 28 And d <= 31 Then
            
                dates = .Cells(r, "F").Resize(, d).Value
                letters = .Cells(r + 1, "E").Resize(3).Value
                counts = .Cells(r + 1, "F").Resize(3, d).Value
                
                For j = 1 To d ' days
                
                    For i = 1 To 3
                        ' update counts
                        counts(i, j) = Application.CountIfs(rngA, dates(1, j), rngB, letters(i, 1))
                    Next
                  
                    ' update table
                    .Cells(r + 1, "F").Resize(3, d) = counts
                Next
            Else
                'Debug.Print r, "No table for month " & m
            End If
        Next
        
    End With
    MsgBox "Done in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 s")
End Sub
```